# Ninject named scoped equivalent in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

We use a hierarchy of different custom named scopes with Ninject in our 
application. But we have been suffering from performance issues with this framework for some time and would like to replace it with simple injector. Unfortunately I cannot find custom scope support in simple injector.

For example we compose a scope in such a way:

```
Bind<ITest>().To<Test>().InNamedScope(InjectionScope.CustomScope.ToString());
```

and the scopes are defined as such for example:

```
Bind<ILeftCustomScope>().To<LeftCustomScope>()
    .DefinesNamedScope(InjectionScope.CustomScope);
Bind<IRightCustomScope>().To<RightCustomScope>()
    .DefinesNamedScope(InjectionScope.CustomScope);
```

Then elsewhere in code:

```
public CustomScopeBuilder(
    IFactory<ILeftCustomScope> left_factory, 
    IFactory<IRightCustomScope> right_factory)
{
    _left_factory = left_factory;
    _right_factory = right_factory;
}

private ICustomScope MakeLeftScope()
{
    return _left_factory.Create();
}

private ICustomScope MakeRightScope()
{
    return _right_factory.Create();
}
```

Comment: [Developing a Custom Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#developing-a-custom-lifestyle)

Comment: Please explain and demonstrate how you use custom scoping. What should be the lifetime of those scoped objects?

Comment: Basically InCustomScope() is just an alias for a number of extension methods that forward to InNamedScope with different names. Then I use DefinesNamedScope to actually define the root objects for those different scopes.

Comment: Fromyour question, it is hard to distill what it is you are trying to achieve, so @qujck's comment is the only correct answer here. If this isn't satisfactory, please update the question and describe what the lifetime of objects should be, around which concept they should be scoped and why you need things to be this way.